# Can not get contacts using qml and v-play

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, v-play, felgo

I cannot get android contacts using v-play nativeUtils. Is there something wrong with this code?

```
 App {
   AppListView {
     anchors.fill: parent
     model:nativeUtils.getContacts()
     delegate:SimpleRow {
       text: modelData.name
       detailText: modelData.phoneNumber
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you add `READ_CONTACTS` permission to manifest?

Comment: yes, I added the permission to mainfest

Answer (score 1):

There is a new property, called `contacts` that you can use for displaying contacts. Have a look at the documentation and the sample here: https://v-play.net/doc/nativeutils/#contacts-prop

Best,
Alex